# Custom android buildTypes not working after upgrade to react-native 0.58

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I upgraded my app from RN0.57.8 to RN0.58.4.
This included changing `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`, and gradle-wrapper from `4.4` to `4.7`.

Now, my app runs fine in debug and release configurations. But I also have custom build type `releaseStaging`. I can successfully build it, but when I run it, it crashes with fatal error: `Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.`

Here are relevant fragments of my `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    // Staging build type:
    // named "releaseStaging" and not just "staging" because of code-push requirements
    bundleInReleaseStaging: true,
    devDisabledInReleaseStaging: true,
    jsBundleDirReleaseStaging: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/releaseStaging",
    resourcesDirReleaseStaging: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/releaseStaging"
]
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Myapp DEBUG"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false"]
    }
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true"]
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Myapp"
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    releaseStaging {
        initWith release
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Myapp STAGING"
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']
    }
}
```

To fix this, I had to downgrade to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4`. I kept version `4.7` of gradle wrapper though.

Does anyone know a way to keep my app's gradle version up-to-date with react-native and use custom android build types?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Android Gradle Plugin 3.2 uses a new `intermediates/merged_assets` directory instead of `intermediates/assets`. This was addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/21409) to react-native. However, their fix doesn't work if you set custom paths like `jsBundleDirReleaseStaging`.

But in react-native 0.58 everything works fine without custom path at all. So I removed `jsBundleDirReleaseStaging` and `resourcesDirReleaseStaging` and gradle fragment for now looks like:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInReleaseStaging: true,
    devDisabledInReleaseStaging: true
]
```